# What is the Tilemill svg export resolution and zoom levels relation?

Tags: svg, export, zooming, mapbox, tilemill

Tilemill works great, mostly very usable! I managed to get to the part where I am making svg exports of my map made with osm-bright as a starter. That seems to be fine but I cant work out how the resolution I specify for the SVG relates to the zoom levels. I guess it has something to do with the tile size, can someone help me understand this?

Thanks a lot, Joris.

Answer (score 0):

First, for printing, the resolution is 90.7 ppi (some OGC standard or whatever). Some round it down to 90 ppi.

Zoom-to-scale relation is calculated [in this table](https://github.com/openstreetmap/mapnik-stylesheets/blob/master/zoom-to-scale.txt): 1:2132 on z18, 1:4265 on z17 and so on. Also see [this page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tilenames#Resolution_and_Scale) on OSM wiki for formulas.